# Unexpected output write listing time slots between time ranges

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, time

I am writing a program to print a range of time slots (hour, minute pairs) between two time ranges (hour, minute). I am seeing unexpected output while running this:

```
import datetime,time
def stamp(hour, min):
    return int(datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 17, hour,min).timestamp())
def ListSlotsAvailable(start, ent, durn):
    secdurn=durn*60
    for sec in range(start, ent, secdurn):
        enttime = sec+secdurn
        print("Stamp is %d-%d" % (sec, enttime))
        print(hour_from_stamp(sec))
        print(min_from_stamp(sec))
        print(hour_from_stamp(enttime))
        print(min_from_stamp(enttime))
def hour_from_stamp(stamp):
    import datetime
    print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(stamp).strftime('%H'))

def min_from_stamp(stamp):
    import datetime
    print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(stamp).strftime('%M'))

starthr=input("Give start time in hour")
startmin=input("Give start time in min")
start=stamp(int(starthr), int(startmin))
endhr=input("Give end time in hour")
endmin=input("Give end time in min")
ent=stamp(int(endhr), int(endmin))
durn=int(input("Give duration for each consultation"))
ListSlotsAvailable(start, ent, durn)
```

Output:

```
Give start time in hour10
Give start time in min15
Give end time in hour12
Give end time in min30
Give duration for each consultation30
Stamp is 1531802700-1531804500
10
None
15
None
10
None
45
None
Stamp is 1531804500-1531806300
10
None
45
None
11
None
15
None
Stamp is 1531806300-1531808100
11
None
15
None
11
None
45
None
Stamp is 1531808100-1531809900
11
None
45
None
12
None
15
None
Stamp is 1531809900-1531811700
12
None
15
None
12
None
45
None

1
```

​
    I didnt expect to see None values there. Where are they coming from?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of printing, your functions should returning those string values instead:

```
def hour_from_stamp(stamp):
    import datetime
    return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(stamp).strftime('%H')

def min_from_stamp(stamp):
    import datetime
    print datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(stamp).strftime('%M')
```

Otherwise a function that does not explicitly return a value would return `None` by default.